# How to prove that the length function is countably additive?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, lebesgue-measure

Found this proof in Inder K. Rana - An Introduction to measure theory and integration

The author wants to prove that $\lambda(I = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_n) =  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda(I_i)$ where $\lambda: \mathcal{I} \to [0, \infty]$ and $\mathcal{I}$ is the set of all possible intervals of the real line.

Now in the line before the last:

why there are inequalities? - it seemed to me it should be like this:

$\lambda(I = \cup_{i=1}^{k} I_n) =  \sum_{i=1}^{k} (b_i - a_i) = b-a$
[image]

Comment: Minor question. Why do you propose $\sum_{i=1}^k(b_i-a_i)=b-a$?

Comment: Because we cut the interval I into disjoint intervals $\cup_{i=1}^k I_i=[a_i,b_i)$

Comment: I'll cut to the chase. The interval $I$ is cut into infinitely many pieces. Restricting attention to a finite collection of pieces of size $k$ results with an inequality not an equality. Put differently, it is not true in general that $\bigcup_{n=1}^kI_n=I$; it is possible if the infinite partition had all but finitely many intervals being the empty interval.

Comment: @AlbertoTakase Ok so you mean that among the intervals $\{I_i\}$ which constitute $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i$ there might exist some empty intervals. So when we pick arbitrarily $k$ intervals of them and we sum their lengths there is no guarantee that they must sum up to the length of $I$. Correct?

Comment: Correct. A finite subcollection may or may not cover the interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emphasis for the inequality is to take advantage of the fact that limits preserve it.

That is to say given a sequence of numbers $(a_n)$ and a constant $C$,
$$a_n\le C\implies \lim a_n\le C$$
provided the limit exists.

The line before last uses $C=\lambda(I)$ and $(a_k)=(\sum_{n=1}^k\lambda(I_n))$. Also note the limit exists by the monotone convergence theorem.